# Visual Studio 2012 Intellisense choosing the wrong item

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

This minor annoyance has started to really irk me lately. When coding, Intellisense often selects the wrong item from the autocomplete menu. This behaviour is common, but not completely consistent. It's been happening for about a week or two.

Here's a [screencast](http://screenr.com/j0qH) I recorded of the behaviour

Anyone have a clue whats happening?

Comment: What update of VS2012 are you on?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the intellisense db? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1757a8bf-27d5-4fb6-8aca-0fb62b3390a5/how-to-force-intellisense-update

Comment: according to that thread I have to delete the .ncb file from the solution directory. There isn't one!

Comment: By the looks of it, pressing 'Enter' always selects the first item in the list of autocomplete suggestions. Is this always the observed behaviour?

Comment: hah, I just played that back for the first time and realised there was sound, whoops! good thing I wasn't humming to myself or whatever. Enter and Tab both triggered the behaviour. However, in the latest version of Visual Studio (2013) it no longer seems to happen